# How to simulate typing in Python 2.7 with multiple lines of simulated typing

Tags: python-2.7

So, I'm making a program for fun. It's basically replacing every print in the original code with simulated typing. So far, I've gotten two parts of the output correct. But, when I try to type another line of simulated typing, it doesn't go to a new line. Here's the code:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

words = "#Project_Blitz_v1.5"
for char in words:
    sleep(0.03)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()

sleep (0.5)

fb = "..."
for char in fb:
    sleep(0.03)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()

words = "eyyyyy"
for char in words:
    sleep(0.03)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

And here's my output:

## Project_Blitz_v1.5...eyyyyy

That "eyyyyy" supposed to be on a different line. How do you put that text on a different line?

Comment: If you're using `sys.stdout.write`, you'll need to explicitly about newlines. Use for example, `sys.stdout.write('\n')` to write a newline to standard output.

Comment: When I did that, it ended up putting each letter of the word on a different line.

Comment: Evert means: outside your loop...